# Definition of 1-Wasserstein distance

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The $W_1$ distance between two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ is defined by

$$
W_1(\mu,\nu)=\sup_{\|f\|_{Lip}\leq 1}\int f(x)d(\mu-\nu)(x)
$$

where $\|f\|_{Lip}$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$.

Can we change this definition to be for positive 1-Lipschitz $f$ ?

Comment: You mean by relaxing that you can replace the condition in the definition with yours?

Comment: yes, I edited my question